# Create csv file using bash script

Tags: bash, csv

I have a script that generates values :

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 1 $3`
do
    total=0
    for  j in `seq 1 $4`
    do
        ./sujet1 $1 $2 $i > mediane
        read iter < mediane
        total=` echo "scale=3; $total + $iter" | bc` 
    done
        med=` echo "scale=3 ; $total/$4"  | bc `
        echo "     "$med
done
```

I want to put *$med* into csv file that create graph on LibreOffice Calc

The bash script used by typing:

```
./bashcrispt.sh $1 $2 $3 $4.
```

Thanks

Comment: Here you have only one column in the .csv file? eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
echo "     "$med
```

to

```
echo $med >>your_csv_file_name.csv
```

Comment: @unfoudev : That did it for you nope? Are you able to open in Libre Office?